# C++11 threading: why does the destructor get called when object is put into a thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Placing the 'thread' code inside overloaded function 'operator()', seems to result in the destructor being called first thing.

Stepping through it in the debugger it looks like literally the first step in the thread is to call the destr.

So the question is, how to place an object into a thread without the destr being called right off the bat.

Here is a program showing 4 ways to place the object in a thread. All of them call the destr prior to the object being used (the 4th way calls it twice).

Note: Using approach number 3, it also does it even if operator() isn't the overloaded function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

class MyClass {
private: int m_id;
public:
    //constr
    MyClass(int id) { m_id=id; std::cout << "constr_" << m_id << "\n";}

    //destr
    ~MyClass() { std::cout << "destr_" << m_id << "\n"; }

    //operator () override for thread
    void operator()() {
        while(true) { 
            std::cout << m_id << "\n"; 
            sleep(1); 
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MyClass m1(1);
    MyClass m2(2);
    MyClass m3(3);

    std::thread thread1 { m1 };
    std::thread thread2(m2);
    std::thread thread3(&MyClass::operator(), m3);
    std::thread thread4{ MyClass(4) };

    thread1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing a copy of MyClass by value, you could pass a smart pointer (e.g. shared_ptr) to instances of MyClass to the thread. This is fine so long as the copy of the smart pointer in main() goes out of scope immediately after the creation of a thread, as is the case in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the objects is destroyed by the newly created thread when it starts. A copy of the object is destroyed when its thread ends. The main thread creates and destroys one or more copies of the object in question. To verify:

```
//constr
MyClass(int id) :m_id(id) { 
    std::cout << " !!! " << m_id << " in " << 
        std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
}

//copy constr
MyClass(const MyClass& other) :m_id(other.m_id) { 
    std::cout << " >>> " << m_id << " in " << 
        std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
}

//destr
~MyClass() { 
    std::cout << " ~~~ " << m_id << " in " 
        << std::this_thread::get_id()  << "\n"; 
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/Xi05uc).

This happens because the object is passed to the thread constructor by copy. This accounts for one copy ctor/dtor pair. The thread constructor stores another copy of the passed object in the thread object, for use by the thread itself. This copy is destroyed at the end of the thread.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense that the pass by value parameter was the thing being destroyed

Answer (score 2):

The class is passed to the thread by value. 
If you look at the [notes on std::thread constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread#Notes) you see the following:

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with std::ref or std::cref).

Thus what happens is that the default copy constructor of your class is called to make a copy of the class and then passing that. 
Your debug output is lying to you. It reports the wrong values.

So to get the correct representation add the following copy constructor to your class then run the code:

```
MyClass(const MyClass& otherr) { m_id=otherr.m_id * 10; std::cout << "constr_" << m_id << std::endl;}
```

The copy constructor will just append zeros to the id each time the object is copied so that you can clearly see what is happening.

The output I get is:

```
constr_1
constr_2
constr_3
constr_10
constr_100
destr_10
constr_20
constr_200
destr_20
constr_30
constr_300
100
200
destr_30
constr_4
constr_40
constr_400
300
destr_40
destr_4
400
200100
```

From the above you can clearly see that 1 is copied (becomes 10) then copied again (100) and then the first copy is destroyed (10) and the second copy is ran in the thread.

The original object will only be destroyed at the end of the program.

Comment: Ok I see. That helps make very clear what exactly was happening. Thank you